# how to deal with plot x axis datetime not continue

Tags: python, axis

Here is my example code:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.dates as md
import pymysql
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pylab as pl

t=[4100,4105,4100,4105,4100,4105,4100,4105,4100,4105,4100,4105]
s=[dt.datetime.now(),dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=1),dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=2),dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=3),
dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=4),
dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=5),
dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=6),
dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=7),
dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=8),
dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=9),
dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(seconds=10),
dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(minutes=1)]


N = len(s)
ind = np.arange(N) # the evenly spaced plot indices

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x+0.5), 0, N-1)
    return  pl.num2date(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(s, t)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Please notice the last datetime element is

```
dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

This means the `x` axis does not continue between the last element and it's previous element, this time range has no data.

When I see the plot above code draw, the result image is just like `w` character, except the last element, because it's time interval is not same as others, so it's far away from it's previous element.

But what I really need is: skip the empty time range of x-axis, and let the last element have same interval in x-axis as others, and remain signal it's time correctly .

I learnt this code mainly from: 
https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/gallery/api/date_index_formatter.html 
but this example seems only deal with skip weekend whole day, cannot skip exactly time range, for example skip 1 hour 20 min in x-axis, can anybody tell me how to finish it ? Thanks.

Comment: please rephrase the parts: (1)"This means...has no data". (2) "and remain signal it's time correctly" ? Not able to get what you mean.

Comment: sorry , I mean the x-axis should be signal as :   dt.datetime.now() ,  dt.datetime.now() +1 second .... , dt.datetime.now() +10 second , dt.datetime.now()+dt.timedelta(minutes=1) ,  but they have same interval